# Spring actuator not logging health endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I am having trouble with Actuator, where I want to get metrics on how many health check requests were made.

This does not show in the `http://localhost:9090/system/metrics/http.server.requests`

I did not find any reason why it shouldn't, and I haven't found anything in the documentation that talks about it.

What kind of configuration will make this work?

```
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
```

> 

```
server:
  port: 8080
  error:
      include-stacktrace: never
management:
  server:
      port: 9090

  endpoint:
      health:
          show-details: never
          enabled: true

  endpoints:
      web:
          base-path: /system
          exposure:
            include: health,info,loggers,metrics,prometheus
```

P.S:
I have managed to get this to work by removing the management port and using the same port as the server itself, but this sounds unreasonable. what am I doing wrong

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error, when I query the metrics endpoint, there is no mention of any calls to /system/health even though I did them. if the management port is the same as the server port, it does log the event

Comment: @Gleeb did you find the issue?